# Algorithm for Encryption

Tags: c++, algorithm, encryption

```cpp
string encrypt(const string message) {
    srand(time(0));
    static int secret = rand() % 32000;
    string output;
    int i = 0, a = 0, b = 1, c = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < message.size(); ++i) {
        output += ((int)message[i]) - (secret + c);
        c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Hey, this is an example of encryption from my teacher. But, I still confuse what does `(int)message[i]` mean? and what does the program do on that line?

Comment: It converts the character at position `i` in the message to its ASCII value (an integer)

Comment: OT: `srand (time(0));` do this only *once* in your program. On most systems `time(NULL)` returns a time with second resolution. If called twice or more within the same second, it will reset the seed to the same value, leading to non-random results from `rand()`. Besides, C++ have had much better [PRNG library functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) than those old C functions for the last 12 or so years.

Comment: @Weetz Or whatever encoding is used on the target system. ASCII is not mandated anywhere by C++.

Comment: Correct. It could be unicode or whatever

Comment: OT: does your teacher not indent their code?

Comment: This can not provide the decryption, but I guess you could guess because the message is protected by only 256 possible states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does `(int)message[i]` mean?

The string `message` can be treated like an array. The expression `message[i]` references the character at position `i`, where the first character is in position zero.

For `std::string`, individual characters have type `char`.

When you output a `char`, using, for example, `std::cout`, it is displayed as a character.

When you use a `char` in an expression, it is treated as an integer value. If, for instance, the underlying character set is ASCII, then the integer value of character `'A'` is 65. `'B'` is 66, and so on.

On most implementations, type `char` is a signed integral type, but that is not required. The C++ Standard also allows it to be an unsigned integral type. Each implementation makes its own choice.

`(int)` is a C-style type cast. It converts the expression that follows it into an `int`. In this case, it converts `message[i]` from type `char` to type `int`. Both are numbers.

> What does the program do on that line?

```cpp
output += ((int)message[i]) - (secret + c);
```

This line encrypts the character at position `i` of the `message`, and appends the result to the end of string `output`.

For type `std::string`, which is the type of variable `output`, `operator+=` is the append operator. It evaluates the expression that follows `+=`, implicitly converts the result to type `char`, and appends it to the string identified on the left of `+=`.

Thanks to @rossum, who identifies the encryption method as a form of *stream cipher.* It uses some arithmetic to convert the integer value of `message[i]` into some other integer value, which is then interpreted as a `char`. For a more precise description, see this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher).

@Neil honed in on the encryption algorithm a little more, pointing out that the "stream" that is subtracted from the plaintext is the Fibonacci sequence, plus a constant, "secret" value.

Comment: The encryption is a form of stream cipher where each character/byte in the plaintext is combined with the current number in the stream. After each stream number is used, the values of `a`, `b` and `c` are changed.

Comment: I think stream cipher is used very loosely. You don't need to calculate all the positions in the stream before to calculate the next letter. It's just subtracting the, essentially standard, Fibonacci sequence from all the letters.